# URL Redirect Based on Target Domain Name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have two domain foo.com and bar.com both pointed to "/var/www/html/".  Few basic HTML pages hosted on Apache2. I want a redirection in ".htaccess" that when some one open "foo.com" it should not have any redirect and it will show up the "index.html" in the "/var/www/html/".  But if some one open "bar.com" then, it should redirect to "http://foo.com/contactus/details.html"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bar.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bar.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foo.com/contactus/details.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

Try this for Redirect an a url to a new url